# Getting the Subview's Main UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Basically, the view hierarchy is like this :
A (UIViewController class)

- B (subview of A.view)(UIView Class)

B, has a class, and one of the functions requires getting some info from A.

What is the best way to invoke a function in A from B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If B is a subview of A, `[B superview]` is A.

**Update 1**

If you're looking for the view *controller* for which A is the `view`, check out [this response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340434/get-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-on-iphone/2596519#2596519). To summarize, according to the [UIResponder documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/nextResponder), if an instance of `UIView` is the `view` of a `UIViewController`, its `nextResponder` will be the view controller (else, `nextResponder` is its `superview`).

**Update 2**

If A is the *controller*, and B is A.view's subview, you can get to A like so:

```
UIResponder *A = [[B superview] nextResponder];
```

Keep in mind that `nextResponder`'s return type is `UIResponder *`, so you might want to verify that A is actually a `UIViewController` using `isKindOfClass:`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But when I tried calling [[B superview] aFunction], it gave reason: '-[UIView aFunction]: unrecognized selector'. Even doing casting for [B superview] does not works.

Comment: Is A a view controller's view?

Comment: Actually. I think I am doing it wrong. Because B is not a subview of A, B is actually A.view's subview.

Comment: Updated my answer regarding B being A.view's subview.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42658-calling-parent-views-method-subview.html

[iPhone how to call a method in parentview from its subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081517/iphone-how-to-call-a-method-in-parentview-from-its-subview)

Comment: I eventually got around the problem by making the function in app delegate (where there is an iboutlet to my A viewcontroller), and using the appdelegate function to call the intended function in the A viewcontroller. This is not a good solution, although it works. There has to be a better way.